# how to search long_word under cursor in vim

Tags: vim, search

I know you can search word under cursor in VIM by # and *, but that search does not work for something  like 'long_word'， e.g., if my cursor is as 'l|ong_word', then I search by # or *, word like 'long' is also considered to be a matching word.

how can I easily search just 'long_word', but not 'long' or 'long_word2', or 'long_long_word'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which characters belong to a *word* is controlled by the `'iskeyword'` option, and this can be different for individual *filetypes*. With

```
:setlocal iskeyword+=_
```

(put into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`), you could achieve this. However, this also affects navigation with commands like `w`, and may impact syntax highlighting, too.

Maybe what you're after is an extension of the `*` and `#` commands to visual mode. With that, you can select arbitrary text and then search for that.

- the [visualstar.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2944) provides this searching of the visual selection
- my [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) has this, and additional search-related extensions and commands (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)